# Help with: Unable to import python module. "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named"

Tags: ros, python, module, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all

I know this question has been asked a lot of times, but it has been mostly relevant to when writing custom python modules and then importing them. My scenario is a bit different, I am trying to use the [nmea_navsat_driver](http://wiki.ros.org/nmea_navsat_driver) package. After cloning, it builds without any warnings/errors with catkin build. However, whenever I try to run the serial driver via. `rosrun nmea_navsat_driver nmea_serial_driver _port:=/dev/ttyUSB0 _baud:=38400`, I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/fpbot/catkin_ws/src/nmea_navsat_driver/scripts/nmea_serial_driver", line 35, in <module> import libnmea_navsat_driver.nodes.nmea_serial_driver

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libnmea_navsat_driver
```

This is a pretty standard package which is widely used. Regardless I have checked the requirements for importing python modules and everything seems to be aligned ros documentation. This leads me to assume that the err is on my end. But I am not able to figure it out. Kindly help.

P.S. I tried other packages which involve importing python modules. The issue was reproduced for each of those packages. Therefore, it is definitely not this particular package.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329382/help-with:-unable-to-import-python-module.-%22modulenotfounderror:-no-module-named%22/) by [Equaltrace](https://answers.ros.org/users/25519/equaltrace/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-07-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you `source`ing your workspace? From the root of your workspace, run

```
source devel/setup.bash
```

Also, why clone and build it yourself? Are you not able to install this package using your package manager? It's available for Ubuntu using

```
sudo apt install ros-<ros-distro>-nmea-navsat-driver
```

Installing it using your package manager is the preferred method, if available of course.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2019-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Equaltrace](https://answers.ros.org/users/25519/equaltrace/) on 2019-07-29**:
Hi jayess

Thanks for the reply. My sincerest apologies for the delayed response.

Yes, I am sourcing from the root of the workspace. It just gets called from the .bashrc file

I tried installing, but that didn't work either. The main reason, I try to clone and build myself is that it allows me to the make modifications to the package if I need to. (In this particular case, no modifications were made)

I tried running the same package on a different machines and it ran successfully. It is probably my ROS or Python setup. I have tried purging and reinstalling ROS but that didn't help. Not exactly sure how to troubleshoot this anymore.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-07-29**:
I'd say that if you don't need to build this package then you should install it using your package manager and avoid this problem.

**Comment by [Equaltrace](https://answers.ros.org/users/25519/equaltrace/) on 2019-08-02**:
@jayess
I did try after installation and got the same issue. I haven't been able to access the device again, but I will try to reinstall ROS and then try again.